# Executing Karate Test suite

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

I am getting ready for a small demo with karate and I have the following git project https://github.com/TheRasanjana/karateTesting. I'm building a Test suite with several features. I have mock-products.feature which I am invoking with my productRunner.java. As I am hoping to integrate this with jenkins in the future I want to execute all of them as a single test suite.

The tests Run successfully when I run each of the runner classes separately. I have a "AllTest.java" runner class outside the features to Run them all as a suite with command "mvn test -Dtest=AllTest". But in that case it won't invoke the mocks. Do I have to invoke the mocks inside AllTests.java as well?

What will be the right way of running all the features as a suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to run mocks in CI is a) use JUnit and b) include the JUnit classes in your test execution. So all you need to do is `mvn test` and you can stop referring to any specific test-runner class.

Actually if you rename `productsRunner` to `ProductsTest` things are likely to start working the way you expect. If you add an `@ignore` to `products.feature` (so they are excluded from `AllTest` and use `@KarateOptions(features = "classpath:features/products/products.feature")` in `ProductsTest` you are all set.

The Karate regression tests use the alternative approach where `ProductsRunner` is explicitly added to the `maven-surefire` section of the `pom.xml`.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>demo/DemoTestParallel.java</include>
                        <include>mock/contract/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>mock/micro/*Runner.java</include>
                        <include>mock/proxy/*Runner.java</include>
                        <include>ssl/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

See the [example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/pom.xml)  and read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#command-line

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response. If I am getting you right what you are telling is to exclude the products.feature from AllTest.java and running AllTest will run the ProductsTest too?

Comment: @NironRasanjanaPerera I realized I did not make it clear that you just need to do `mvn test` I think that was what you were missing. edited my answer.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I was bit confused. Anyway it worked as you said.